# Select parent directory if non-unique directory is found

Tags: bash

Hello I am trying to figure out how I can parse directories using built-in bash functionality.

The directory structure would look something like.

```
/home/mikal/PluginSDK/vendor_name1/ver1/plugin_name/plugin-config.json  
/home/mikal/PluginSDK/vendor_name1/ver2/plugin_name/plugin-config.json  
/home/mikal/PluginSDK/vendor_name2/ver1/plugin_name/plugin-config.json  
/home/mikal/PluginSDK/vendor_name3/plugin_name/plugin-config.json
```

So far I have narrowed down  to the name of the plugin which covers most of what I needed for the rest of the script.

```
find  /home/mikal/PluginSDK -type f -name plugin-config.json | sed -r 's|/[^/]+$||' | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'
```

The problem that I am running into is when the same vendor has different versions of plugin available for the same release. We may not always want to run a newer version of the plugin due to compatibility or performance of the plugin so having these show something like ver1-plugin_name or similar would be preferrable. I can't find anything that would be able to pick out the non-unique plugin/version so that I can make an array with all of the options.

This is the entirety of what I have written right now for this section of the script I am writing to make configuration changes to the system.

```
options=()
while IFS= read -r line; do  
    options+=( "$line" )  
done < <( find  /home/mikal/PluginSDK -type f -name plugin-config.json | sed -r 's|/[^/]+$||' | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' )  
select opt_number in "${options[@]}" "Quit";  
  do  
    if [[ $opt_number == "Quit" ]];  
      then  
        echo "Quitting"  
      break;  
    else  
      find /home/mikal/PluginSDK -type f -name plugin-config.json -exec sh -c "sed -i 's/"preferred": true/"preferred": false/g'" {} \;  
      find /home/mikal/PluginSDK/${options[$(($REPLY-1))]} -type f -name plugin-config.json -exec sh -c "sed -i 's/"preferred": false/"preferred": true/g'" {} \;  
      break;  
    fi  
done
```

Desired output for the entire thing would be something like.

1.) Ver1-Plugin_name
2.) Ver2-Plugin_name
3.) Plugin_name
4.) Plugin_name
5.) Quit

I apologize if my formatting is bad. First time posting.

Comment: Add your desired output of your `find ... | sed ... | awk ...` command (no description) for that sample input (4 rows) to your question.

Comment: Hope what I added is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

```
lst=( Quit 
      $( find  /home/mikal/PluginSDK -type f -name plugin-config.json |
           awk -F/ '{ if (7==NF) { print $6 } else { print $6"-"$7 } }' )
select opt_number in "${lst[@]}"
. . .
```

You might want to c.f. [BashFAQ 20](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) if your filenames could have any weirdness like embedded spaces.

Comment: Thank you that seems to do exactly what I want it to!

Comment: [Accept the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? :)